# Send colleague a Flex POC with XML

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4

I've been asked to put together a proof of concept where Flex loads an XML file. I did and now I'd like to email the SWF and XML file and have the user just click and work instead of putting it up on a server.

I've added use-network=false in my compiler arguments but that doesn't work. I'm still seeing a blank screen.

Any ideas on how I can do this, please?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you expect the user to click?  The SWF file?  If so, system settings will control what happens and you may not have control over those settings.

Comment: Exactly. I want them to click the SWF file right from the email and have it work.

Comment: You really should put the SWF on a web server and send them a link.  I believe it is the only way to ensure that the file will work for the user and that the XML file--which I assume is not embedded--will be in the proper location.

Comment: How about create an air application?

Comment: What Flextras said.  I'm sure you can find easy/free hosting somewhere.  If anything, you could always compile your project into an Air executable so that the xml is packaged with it, but it's more work and he would need to install the Air app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zip your bin-debug folder. Make sure your xml is in there as well. Send it across and ask them to launch the swfFile.htm file in the bin-debug folder.
Note: bin-debug folder is referred as output folder in your Flex project.

Comment: I like this solution and should've done it first. In the end I just ended putting it up on a web server. Thank you for all helpful comments.

Answer (score 1):

Put the xml file on a web server and you won't have an issue.

If you want it to read from the local disk, open the .swf in the viewer and create a projector file - then it will be able to access the local hard drive without issue.

Let me know how it goes :)